# Uploading XML file to AWS s3 using java

Tags: java, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload XML file from one bucket to another using aws SDK.

```
// Download the XML from S3 into a stream
        AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
        S3Object s3Object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(
                srcBucket, srcKey));
        InputStream objectData = s3Object.getObjectContent();
```

and to upload the file,

```
 s3Client.putObject(dstBucket, dstKey, objectData, meta);
```

Executing the lambda function throws

```
More data read than expected: dataLength=367; expectedLength=1; ...
```

Is there anything I am missing out? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is copying of the same object from source to destination bucket, we can use

```
 CopyObjectRequest copyObjRequest = new CopyObjectRequest(
            srcBucket, srcKey, dstBucket, dstKey);
    s3Client.copyObject(copyObjRequest);
```